# Use React-router to change components but not the main url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i want to know if it's possible to use react-router to handle my components rendering, but not showing any urls just changing all uder the hood.

I want to create a website "plugin" who will have many pages inside with links, but it must not interfere with the main website. Whatever which language it's made of.

Is it possible? And how can i start it? I'm used to react-router, but not in this kind of project.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can use Memory History to it: https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/990b853671b84230f59e0523682ec635a6c3dbc4/docs/GettingStarted.md#getting-started

Comment: it's also mentionend in the [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#creatememoryhistory) documentation, so should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [memory history](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#creatememoryhistory) to do it.

It maintains all state in memory without touching your URL :)

Comment: Thank you, really appreciated!